# Maximum frequency of a number using hashmaps. Alternative approach

Tags: java, hashmap

```
 public static int maxFrequencyNumber(int[] arr){

        HashMap<Integer,Integer> m = new HashMap<>();


     for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(m.containsKey(arr[i]))
            m.put(arr[i],m.get(arr[i])+1);
         else
             m.put(arr[i],1);

     }
       ArrayList<Integer> p = new ArrayList<>();

     Set<Integer> s = m.keySet();   
        for(Integer i:s)
           p.add(m.get(i));

           Collections.sort(p);


         for(Integer i:s){
             if(m.get(i)==p.get(p.size()-1))
                 return i;


         }
        return 0;

    }
```

You are given an array of integers that contain numbers in random order. Write a program to find and return the number which occurs the maximum times in the given input.

If two or more elements contend for the maximum frequency, return the element which occurs in the array first.

**I am getting correct output except for one case in which all elements in an array have same frequency.whats wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that a `HashMap` does not record the order in which its entries are inserted.  So when there is a "tie" in frequency, your code could return any one of the corresponding keys.

If you change `HashMap` to `LinkedHashMap` in your code, you guarantee that the entries will be iterated in the same order they were originally inserted.  This will solve your problem.